# issues installing phpmyadmin in RHEL7

Tags: phpmyadmin, redhat

I'm going to install phpmyadmin in my RHEL7 VM, and it keeps prompting error messages as below:

```
    Error: Package: php-tcpdf-6.2.13-1.el7.noarch (epel)
       Requires: php-mbstring
    Error: Package: php-php-gettext-1.0.12-1.el7.noarch (epel)
       Requires: php-mbstring
    Error: Package: phpMyAdmin-4.4.15.10-2.el7.noarch (epel)
       Requires: php-mbstring >= 5.3.7
    Error: Package: php-tcpdf-6.2.13-1.el7.noarch (epel)
       Requires: php-bcmath
     You could try using --skip-broken to work around the problem
     You could try running: rpm -Va --nofiles --nodigest
```

I tried to install the missing packages one by one but when I tried to install php-mbstring, it prompts out some other dependencies error as well.

Is there any solution for this kind of issue? I have no issues installing in CentOS 7.

Comment: I'm using command "yum install phpmyadmin" FYI

Comment: The missing packages are in the `rhel-7-server-optional-rpms` repository.